# BeagleBone uart/spi/i2c latency

Tags: i2c, beagle-bone

There seems to be consensus here that the BeagleBone Black has 1ms+ latency while toggling gpio pins due to the fact that gpio is handled outside of the cpu. Are the uart/i2c/spi lines equaly slow, or are they significantly faster?

I've seen references to people talking to the gpio [more directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124271/driving-beaglebone-gpio-through-dev-mem). Could this decrease uart/i2c/spi latencies as well?

Comment: What level of performance do you need?

Comment: 300 to 500μs would be ideal for my application. From what I can find the BBB supports up to 3mbaud uart, so an added 1ms can be a lot at those levels. However, I doubt it would be too noticeable in the i2c world...